# ListBox of anonymous UIElements

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, listbox, uielement

I want to create a `ListBox` and fill it with anonymous `UIElement`. In other words, the `DataTemplate` of the `ItemTemplate` will contain only one element, and afterwords during the runtime, afterwards I will create in the code behind different `UIElement`s (`TextBlock`s, `Grid`s ...) and populate the list with it.

So how am I going to write the `DataTemplate` of the `ListBox`? And how am I intend to use an `ObservableCollection` for the `ItemSource`?  So should use an `ObsevableCollection` of `UIElement`?

Comment: Would not recommend having lists containing any UI elements. Introduce some model-view-separation, e.g. MVVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Question: **No** `DataTemplate`. Since your items are already `UIElement`s, you don't need a `DataTemplate`.

And if you're creating a changeable collection, then yes, `ObservableCollection<UIElement>` is the way to go.

Now, *why* would you be doing this? You may want to ask yourself if this is the best way of doing things. Why isn't your data and your presentation separated? If you need more than one type of element in the list, will [`DataTemplateSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) allow you to have a real `ViewModel`?

Comment: What I want exactly is a list of TextBlocks and Grids containing TextBlocks. I want to use then so that the user will mark and edit each text block individually, and I before all this populate the list based on the user choise wheather the grid comes first or the TextBlock.

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like you should be using a `DataTemplateSelector`. You would assing the `ItemTemplateSelector` on the `ListBox`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <ListBox x:Name="name" ItemsSource="{Binding source}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <textbox x:Name="name"></ToggleButton> //or any tool
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```